# Retrieve deleted file where delete was committed

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using `Egit` on `Eclipse Oxygen` and have been unable to find a way to retrieve a file that was deleted from the workspace and the delete was committed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check it out from previous commit. Look at the project history in 'Team' contextual menu.

Comment: As I understand it, this only works if you want to retrieve an earlier version of an existing file. In my case the Team contextual menu does not seem to offer the opportunity because the delete has been committed.

Comment: Previous commits where the file was present are still there. Find the latest commit where the file was "alive" and check it out.